# How would you show that there is no difference between three groups?

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, univariate

I'm trying to convey data as such:
[image]

Unfortunately I have not found a better way than to run a multinomial regression and then show that there at least is no difference between groups A, B and then the base C. Is there any statistical way to have ONE p-value to say that there is no difference between any of the groups for all their permutations? (i.e. A and B, B and C, A and C etc.)?

I ran two ANOVA models here: imgur.com/a/qUgXt7t

[image]

The top one I clicked "suppress constant" in stata. Does this mean there is a significant difference between the gender of the groups? The second is simply a normal anova

Comment: It is clear what is your data, can you describe it in English and not only as a table?  But look into ANOVA and its glm-generalizations!

Comment: ANOVA does the same thing. Compares the three groups but always with one base and the other two comparing against it (i.e. 2 p-values).

Comment: If you have only the groupiing factor variable, represent the ANOVA as regression and omit the intercept!

Comment: I ran two models here: https://imgur.com/a/qUgXt7t

The top one I clicked "suppress constant" in stata. Is that what you mean? Does this mean there is a significant difference between the gender of the groups? The second is simply a normal anova.

Comment: Please edit your post with this new information!

Comment: All right, I have added it.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Is your read of this not that it is equivalence testing but with more than two groups?

Comment: @Dave that is what I'm trying to do, yes.

Comment: Am I just supposed to run a simple ANOVA? Maybe I'm being obtuse.

Comment: Please do not give output from analysis only as an image ref in comments! Few people will bother --- for now I am editing it in the post, but in the future do so yourself!

Comment: Is the answer here to simply run ANOVA assuming normal data? If so, someone can post that and I will accept it.

Comment: @Paze You probably don't want to use the model without a constant, unless you have a good reason to do so. ...  I don't know if I'm being pedantic, but I'm wondering about "*show that there ... is no difference between groups*".  An anova or multiple regression doesn't ***show*** that there is no difference.  But instead that with the data collected that there isn't good evidence that you can detect a difference given the variability in the data. ...  It might be that once you establish a minimum difference among groups that is meaningful, that you use confidence intervals or multiple TOSTs.